# On iOS devices only, black assets when programmatically creating assets. Works fine on any other browser

Tags: aframe

I am creating assets programmatically and would like to continue doing that. I know that the `<a-asset>` tag is preloading the data but I would like it created at load. For example (see URL below) the first link works fine creating it via javascript. On browsers, android phones, etc. it loads the assets just fine. When you load it up on iPhone the asset is blacked out. I assume only that the asset isn't loading. I tried playing with timeouts on assets but that does not seem to work. When you manually insert the `<img>` tag in the body, it will load the asset fine. The second URL shows that it works when I enter the data in statically.

A-Frame Version: 1.0.4
Platform / Device: iOS 13 - iPhone
Reproducible Code Snippet or URL: https://fork-secretive-princess.glitch.me/ and https://fork-secretive-princess.glitch.me/static.html

Comment: Is the asset an svg?

Comment: @AHaworth no, just a png